# Create dns entries in route 53 using boto

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-route53

I am looking for a way to pass a json file using boto which will have dns entries and this dns entries can be made in route 53 as fast as possible.

Appreciate any possible help, direction or anything.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: using aws cli, we can do a batch request as documented here- [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/route53/change-resource-record-sets.html)
Trying to figure out how to do this using boto ??

Comment: If you already have a Json file. Why don't you do it with CloudFormation?

Comment: Actually I would like to run a script say every 30 seconds and see if there are any new machines scaled up which could go upto 100, then for all these scaled up machines, create a json file containing instance details and make dns entries in a batch request instead of sequentially....

Comment: Add a sns notification for each newly autoscaled instance. send it to sqs queue. write a script which gathers info from sqs queue about instance ip and other details and generates the required records in AWS Route53....This would be your required script

Comment: Have you considered having the instances register themselves via User Data? The only problem would then be removing entries for terminated instances.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Could you please share link to refer to ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford to keep the script running for every 30 seconds it is great.

**You can write a python script which does the following.**

- Trigger a SNS notification for each autoscaled Instance using cloudwatch metrics
- Bind SNS with a SQS queue.
- Retrieve information from SQS queue. (instance IP and Hostname)
- Generate required Route53 records using the information according to your requirement.
- If instance is deleted removed its associated records.

Comment: this is the current mechanism we already have in place, but it fails as we have dependency on queues. To scale up 100 machines, it take a lot of time. :(

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to add a DNS entry for newly-created instances, then you could have the **instances register themselves**.

A [user data script](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) can be run automatically when an instance boots for the first time. This script could call the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to register a new DNS entry in Route 53.

The script would do the following:

- Create a JSON file with the desired DNS `CREATE` entry
- Call the `aws route53 change-resource-record-sets` command

See: [AWS CLI documentation for change-resource-record-sets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/route53/change-resource-record-sets.html)

However, you'd have to find a way to delete DNS entries when instances are terminated.